# Salesforce Lightning - event(s) fire on publishing a chatter post

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using `forceChatter:publisher`lightning component and would like to invoke some functionality when user click on "Share" button.
[image]

Is there any event I could listen to? In Salesforce lightning inspector I can see application event is firing (`forceChatter:postCreated`) but when I add a handler for that event type it doesn't seem to work. eg. 
`<aura:handler name="forceChatter:postCreated" event="forceChatter:postCreated" action="{!c.chatterPosted}"/>`

Any ideas? Your help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer. Will leave an answer for future reference.

Since `forceChatter:postCreated` is an application event, we don't need to define name in the handler so the correct handler should be as follows.

`<aura:handler event="forceChatter:postCreated" action="{!c.chatterPosted}"/>`